# Hibernate Mapping Through Another Entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

Consider this simple database schema:

```
 User                Course              StudentCourse       Student
+-------------+     +-------------+     +-------------+     +-------------+
| -user_id    |1   *| -course_id  |1   *| -course_id  |*   1| -student_id |
|             |---->| -user_id    |---->| -student_id |---->|             |
+-------------+     +-------------+     +-------------+     +-------------+

[1   *] = 1 to many relationship
```

I have created entities for the User, Course, and Student objects, and set up the following mappings:

```
User   -> Course  - one to many
Course -> Student - many to many
```

In my Java classes I can access the Courses of a User by calling `user.getCourses()` and I can access all the Students in a Course by calling `course.getStudents()`. **I want to be able to find all of the Students in all of the Courses taught by a specific User** like `user.getCourse().getStudents()`, but because `user.getCourses()` returns `Collection<Course>` I cannot call `course.getStudents()` on the Collection. **How should I implement this with Hibernate?** Is a named query my only option?

Answer (score 1):

i guess you have to define fetchType = EAGER in Course, which is actually not a good idea 
so HQL would be best and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
for ( Course course : user.getCourses() )
{
    students.addAll( course.getStudents() );
}
```

However this would be very inefficient (see the "[SELECT N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)" problem)

I haven't had a chance to test it but your named query should just be something like:
"SELECT c.students FROM Course c WHERE c.user.name = 'username'"

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I want to be able to find **all of the Students in all of the Courses** taught by a specific User

Use HQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT _student FROM User AS _user, IN ( _user.courses ) _course, IN( _course.students ) _student WHERE _user.id = :id
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT _student FROM User _user inner join _user.courses _course inner join _course.students _student WHERE _user.id = :id
```

regards,